# Tensorflow: Retraining inception v3 shows 0 % GPU usage

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am currently trying out Tensorflow's inception model and while it does use the GPU for bottlenecks generation, it doesn't seem to do anything on it training-wise.

- GPU usage is monitored through `nvidia-smi`, it stays at 0%
- log_device_placement returns gpu:0 for about 80% of operation so it seems fine.
- At the beginning it does detect my Titan X with the usual `/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0`
- The memory on the GPU is allocated
- CUDA is installed and so is cuDNN both last version
- The temperature does rise (about 20 celsius 40->60) but it could be the CPU heating the whole case?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check whether GPU is used with nvprof. It can tell for sure.

For many models, check the argument to specify GPU count. For example: num_gpus. A few examples default to not to use GPU unless specified.

Comment: I have the same exact issue, the thing is, that I see that both GPUs are fully loaded with memory but only one is being used, another proof that it can be done faster is that there is no "model training time" difference between one GPU or multiple on this machine